# Who can LOCK my forum post in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, locked

I want to ask "Who can LOCK my forum post in stackoverflow"
Because I try to make my own forum.
And I want to know best practices.
If I should to give opportunity to user to lock his post when he has already answer of the question.

Sorry if my question is duplicate.
If has similar question. Can you give me a link where I can read a practices.

Best Regards.

Comment: not me.. I cannot lock it, yet!

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a forum.

Comment: "Because I try to make my own forum. And I want to know best practices." That is off-topic here...or anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Please don't make your own forum. There are more than enough of those out there already. And unless you have [some *radical new ideas*](http://www.discourse.org/), it won't be any better than those that already exist.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I think OP meant "creating a new community" not "writing new software"...at least I hope that...

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: even then, chances are that the community he's trying to create already has a place ... or 5 ... or 10.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: That's true, but I don't think we should limit or discourage hat diversity...if it ends up as a place used by 5 people, that's still 5 people happy and if it fails no one cares anyway (and OP learned something). But I agree with your "don't write a new one" statement...especially when OP is using PHP \*shutters\* the horrors I've seen in the PHP tag...

Comment: For best practise for a form you're building, as on http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

### Stack Overflow is not a forum.

However, if you are talking about not allowing any more answers on a particular post, then it can be done by the moderators of Stack Overflow or privileged users who can vote to close your question. Once the post reaches 5 votes, it is automatically closed.

It is called "closing" and the question is deemed as "closed", which means no more answers are allowed on that post.

**NOTE :** "Closing" of posts is not done when a user has found a solution to the problem. It is usually done when the question does not conform to the principles and guidelines of the website.

Also note that closed posts can be voted for re-opening by the users who have the privileged. And when there are 5 votes to re-open a previously closed post, then the post is opened again.